# Is it possible to force Play Framework to compile all js files in only one via RequireJS?

Tags: playframework, requirejs, playframework-2.1

Using Play-Framework 2.1(rc4) and the "built-in" RequireJS, everything works great, and Play successfully compress (uglify) all my JS files in PROD, but I'd like it to join all of them in one JS file.

Is this possible? If yes, how to do so ? Is there a build.js to make with these directives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You have to add the `requireJsShim` in the Build.scala file. Often, the value of `requireJsShim` is the same as the `requireJs` property.

Once you've done that, everything will be compiled in one file!

There is an example project for Play 2.1.0: https://github.com/schleichardt/play-2.1-features/tree/stackoverflow-question-14704169 (it is not in the master but in the stackoverflow-question-14704169 branch)

play dist

(! means in JAR or ZIP)

And dist/play-2-1-features-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip!play-2-1-features-1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/play-2-1-features_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!public/javascripts-min/main.js contains all JavaScript/CoffeeScript code.

Comment: From what I've checked, the main.js only contains the javascript from the original main.js file, not all the js files imported from RequireJS (define,import)

Comment: Did you checkout the correct branch (stackoverflow-question-14704169) and used `play dist`

Comment: Ok, well in fact it was missing the `requireJsShim` configuration. I updated your answer to match this, and then accepted it. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction !